# Best way to check if there is a 0 in an integer

Tags: optimization, language-agnostic

What is the best way to check if there's **0**(zero) in an integer

For example:

```
505 -> True
555 -> False
44444032 -> True
0000 -> True
```

I have tried this

```
public bool has0(int no)
{
    if(no==0)return true;
    while(no!=0)
    {
        if(no%10==0)return true;
        no=no/10;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works,but it takes time specially on large numbers given the fact that i need to call this method **1 billion** times specifically on large numbers

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)has0(i);
```

So,what would be the best way to check if 0 exist in a number by using some bit level operators like `|`,`&`,`^` or any other way.

Thanks..

Comment: and yes i would like to have answers from **any** of the tagged languages

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157914/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-has-the-digit-zero-anywhere-in-it][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157914/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-number-has-the-digit-zero-anywhere-in-it

Comment: 0000 is not an integer

Comment: @sectus you should take a [tutorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) on integer..:)

Comment: really all the languages and a billion times.

Comment: I pretty much doubt that any of the tags really make sense. This is not about optimizations and it is really language agnostic...

Comment: @Dagon `0000` is similar to `0`..

Comment: cats are similar to asteroids.

Comment: @Dagon nice knowing that..thanks for the info

Comment: I changed your tags to the SO standards. Also, `no=no/10;` should be `no /= 10;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [checking an integer to see if it contains a zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847479/checking-an-integer-to-see-if-it-contains-a-zero)

Comment: @TedHopp do i need to tell you a 1000 times..i need optimized code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modulo is an expensive integer operation (similar to integer divides).  You could eliminate half of the possible answers in your test by seeing if the number is even.  No odd number has a modulo 10 equal to zero.

if (((no & 0x1) == 0x00) && ((no % 10) == 0))
  return true;

You will pay a little more on the even numbers, but a lot less on the odd ones.  Hence, if it's all even numbers, this won't help (it will actually hurt), but if it's 50/50 or even 20/80 (20 percent odd), you'll probably still come out ahead.

Also, integer multiply is less expensive, so you may just do the divide first and calculate the modulo 10.

```
while (no)
{
  if (no & 0x1))  // odd?
    no /= 10;
  else  // even
  {
    int nNext = no / 10;  // just do integer divide, and calculate modulo in next line
    if ((no - (10 * nNext)) == 0)  // replaces "more expensive" modulo operation with integer multiply and subtraction
      return true;
    no = nNext;
  }
}
```

Comment: my code took about 97 seconds to process 1 billion numbers..your brilliant ans reduced it by **30 seconds**..hats off to your brilliant idea....

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted answer is definitely faster than the original code, an approach utilizing a lookup table is going to be a lot faster still.

On my slow-ish laptop, it took your original code ~28s to handle 250 million numbers, and ~23s with the code from the accepted answer. Using a lookup table, it took just over **7s**.

It becomes obvious why when you look at the code:

```
bool HasZero(int num)
{
    if (num < 100000) return lookup[num];

    int upperDigits = num / 100000;
    int lowerDigits = num - (upperDigits * 100000);

    return lookup[upperDigits] || lowerDigits < 10000 || lookup[lowerDigits];
}
```

The code has a *maximum* of one division, one subtraction, one multiplication, two comparisons, and two array lookups. Even optimized, going digit by digit can be *much* worse than that. And pre-computing the lookup table takes a trivial amount of time (< 1ms).

Note that the code won't quite work if you're not working with 32-bit integers, since then you would need to verify a third set of digits (or increase the size of the lookup table from 10^5 to 10^6; I imagine it would still be faster.)

Comment: return lookup[upperDigits] || lowerDigits < 10000 || lookup[lowerDigits] will short circuit and return true.  I think you meant to do return lookup[upperDigits] || (lowerDigits < 10000 && lookup[lowerDigits]) just do bounds check the array, so the timing shouldn't change by much.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to make it utilize a smaller lookup table and use recursion, if memory was an issue (e.g. 2 or 3 digits, so a table of 100 or 1000 bits), or if you needed to use it with even larger integers, the recursive routine would just handle it.  This, of course. assumes the language of choice supported recursion.

Comment: For the return statement, the three different `||`s is intentional: we know that `lowerDigits` is already less than 100000 (since we did the equivalent of a % 100000.) The check for < 10000 ensures that we don't return false for a number like 100123: in that case, upperDigits is 1 (no zeros) and lowerDigits is 123 (also no zeros.) Also, I agree that a smaller lookupTable is definitely doable, though if the memory is available, 100000 seemed to produce the best results.

Comment: Doh!  Now I get it (wish we had commas)

Answer (score 0):

Just a small idea. Division by a constant may be replaced by a multiply and shift sequence. If the compiler or virtual machine that you're using has a clue, then it will do this itself. If it's stupid, you can get some major speed-up by inserting the multiply and shift sequence manually. For example, for the Java HotSpot Client VM, I've found that the technique below (correct for non-negative n) is more than twice as fast as the obvious way (commented out) of doing the division, and five times as fast as the original loop using modulo.

```
static boolean has0(int n) {
    do {
        //int divided = n / 10;
        int divided = (int)((n * 0xCCCCCCCDL) >>> 35);
        if (divided * 10 == n) return true;
        n = divided;
    } while (n != 0);
    return false;
}
```

But for the Java HotSpot Server VM, which is less braindead, the obvious way is already fast, and this trick doesn't help, or even makes it slower. Unfortunately with this sort of very low level optimization you have to be prepared to retune it for different languages and language implementations.

Read about the [weird and wonderful complexities of microbenchmarking in Java](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp12214/) before you try to measure something like this though.

Answer (score -4):

If no==0 your function will return false. Apart from that I can't see how you can do better.